# Can't get out of the Visual Studio 2019 sandbox to access LAN

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2019

I’m using Visual Studio 2019 to develop a Taskpane for Excel to download sensor data to a spreadsheet. I’m obtaining the data over Wi-Fi via an ESP8266 TCP socket server module which is a node on my LAN(thus the URL 192.168.0.7:81). The html and Javascript work fine in Internet Explorer(IE). There is no password or LAN SSID involved.
The Javascript builds fine in VS2019 but immediately fails in debug.

Javascript:

Home.js contains:
line 8 - var connection = new WebSocket(‘ws://’ + ‘192.168.0.7’ + ‘:81/’, [‘arduino’]);

Upon Debug:
Build Succeeded with 0 Errors

'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (Windows Internet Explorer)'. 
Unhandled exception at line 8, column 1 in https://localhost:44390/Home/Home.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SecurityError

The program '[11136] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The program '[2236] EXCEL.EXE' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The program '[10844] iexplore.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).

I’ve looked everywhere for explanations of the 0x800a139e SecurityError but found nothing that helped solve the problem.
It appears to be a general JS syntax error but the code works fine in IE and IE is the selected browser in VS2019. Running Code Analysis shows no errors with the JS. Note: I'm using straight JS for this not jquery because, as I understand it, jquery is simply a library that converts to JS for compilation and I have no clue how this line would be constructed in jquery.
Also, if I use Tools/Connect to Server it cannot find 192.168.0.7. Is this because it only looks for sql servers or because I have a VS2019 configuration problem?
This is most frustrating due to lack of specific error definition.

Thanks

Comment: Playing with sockets isn't really my thing. I thought I would comment though and say that you don't have to run iisexpress. You can run an IIS instance locally and then attach to process in VS2019 in debug. Maybe this would mitigate your issue when debugging?

Comment: Thanks, actually I think that's exactly what IISExpress is doing. I certainly didn't invoke it in any way. I'm very suspicious of IIS but I can't see anything that would indicate that it's causing this issue although it has caused problems during compile if VS2019 was not run as Administrator. Again, thanks.